# Conditional PMF for $P_X(x) = \frac{2(x - a + 1) }{(b-a+1)(b-a+2)}$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

The PMF of random variable $X$, is given by:

$$P_X(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{2(x - a + 1) }{(b-a+1)(b-a+2)} & a \leq x \leq b \\ 0 &\mathrm{otherwise}.  \end{cases}$$

Assume $a < 0$ and $b \geq 0$.

Let $A$ be the event $\{X < 0\}$. Find $P_{X|A}(x)$

Comment: Have you tried applying the definition of conditional probability?

Comment: When the _conditioning_ event $A$ is specified in terms of $X$, the
conditional pdf of $X$ given $A$ has a very simple form: it has value $0$
on the set $A^c$ and value $\displaystyle\frac{f_X(x)}{P(A)}$ on the set $A$.

Comment: I know about the concept but can't apply it to get a solution in formula. More details please. Thanks.

Comment: Have you ever considered the possibility of _sketching_ the density function given to you? Go ahead, try it. It is not as hard as you think. If you have the gumption, you might even think of _labeling_ the axes and various points where the function changes shape or value etc. Then, consider whether _anything_ that you have learned thus far allows you to calculate $P(A)$.